# A deleted default constructor could still be trivial?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Looking at the definition of trivial default constructor in the standards:

> A default constructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> - its class has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
> - no non-static data member of its class has a brace-or-equal-initializer, and
> - all the direct base classes of its class have trivial default constructors, and
> - for all the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial default
>     constructor.
>
> Otherwise, the default constructor is non-trivial.

It seems that the definition of a default constructor's triviality doesn't rule out the possibility of a `deleted` default constructor:

```
struct A {
    int& a;  // the implicitly defaulted default constructor will be defined as deleted
};

struct B {
    B()=delete;  // explicitly deleted
};

int main() {
    static_assert(is_trivial<A>::value, "");
    static_assert(is_trivial<B>::value, "");
}
```

The above code runs without any assertion failure.  The type has trivial default constructor and is trivially copyable, so it's a `"trivial class"`.

Wouldn't making this kind of type as `"trivial class"` bring trouble?  E.g., for things like object lifetime, byte-wise copy equivalence, `goto` statement allowance etc.

**EDIT: The following example of goto allowance is not valid.  Thank you for @Casey's comment.  Another example of byte-wise copy equivalence is added to replace this one.**

<s>Take `goto` statement allowance as an example, the standards says:</s>

> It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that
>   bypasses declarations with initialization. A program that jumps87 from
>   a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in
>   scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the
>   variable has scalar type, class type with a trivial default
>   constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of
>   these types, or an array of one of the preceding types and is declared
>   without an initializer (8.5).

So for the following code:

```
class A {
    int& a;
public:
    A(int& aa): a{aa} {}
    A()=default;  // this is necessary otherwise no default constructor will be implicitly declared then the type will not be trivial
};

int i;

int main() {
    static_assert(is_trivial<A>::value, "");
    goto L;
    A a{i};
L:
    return 0;
}
```

It is well-formed according to the rules because `A` has a trivial default constructor and a trivial destructor (the assertion passes OK).  On the opposite, the code is ill-formed in C++03 (with C++11-only syntax removed, i.e. the line of `A()=default;`), because `A` is not a `POD` in C++03, and C++03 allows `goto` to cross definition of `POD` type only.

Take byte-wise copy equivalence as an example, the standard says:

> For any trivially copyable type T, if two pointers to T point to
>   distinct T objects obj1 and obj2, where neither obj1 nor obj2 is a
>   base-class subobject, if the underlying bytes (1.7) making up obj1 are
>   copied into obj2,41 obj2 shall subsequently hold the same value as
>   obj1.

So `memcpy()` on trivially copyable type is well-defined:

```
class A {
    int& a;
public:
    A(int& aa): a{aa} {}
    A()=default;  // this is necessary otherwise no default constructor will be implicitly declared then the type will not be trivial
    void* addr() {return &a;}
};

int i = 0;
int j = 0;

int main() {
    static_assert(is_trivial<A>::value, "");
    A a{i};
    A b{j};
    cout << a.addr() << " " << b.addr() << "\n";
    // a = b;  // this will be ill-formed because the implicitly defaulted copy assignment is defined as deleted
    memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof(A));  // this is well-defined because A is trivial
    cout << a.addr() << " " << b.addr() << "\n";
}
```

It is well-defined according to the rules because `A` is a trivial type (the assertion passes OK).  The result shows that a reference is made to refer to different objects at different times.  On the opposite, the code is undefined in C++03 (with C++11-only syntax removed, i.e. the line of `A()=default;`), because `A` is not a `POD` in C++03, and C++03 allows byte-wise copy equivalence of `POD` type only.

Comment: There is a difference between clang and gcc here. On `gcc 4.8.2` those assertions (and `has_trivial_default_constructor`) fail. On `clang` from a recent SVN build they pass.

Comment: Doesn't a constructor have to exist to be trivial or nontrivial?

Comment: @pmr: I just added an example of `goto` allowance to express my doubt.

Comment: @user2357112: Yeah, that's the point of my question because the language rule seems to conflict with one's common sense.

Comment: @pmr `clang version 3.5.0 (205153)` here, under `Ubuntu Saucy amd64` and the first snippet of code fails at compile time with both `clang++` from the svn and `g++ 4.8.1`. ( the same is true for the second example ).

Comment: What's the actual question? Yes, it seems it's trivial but what do you want answered? Doesn't seem to be a reference to "brings trouble" in the standard.

Comment: @goodbyeera you should specify the compiler/s that you used and the options that you gave, as it is now your question doesn't make sense because the assertions are valid in both `gcc` and `clang`.

Comment: @david.pfx: If deleted default constructor can still be trivial (which is of course still in question by now), then goto statement can cause object in ill-initialized state as the second code sample illustrates.

Comment: @user2485710: Clang 3.5 (trunk 198621)

Comment: @user2485710: I didn't mention the specific version of compiler I used in the question because I believe the question is still viable even if no major compilers compile the sample code.  It's a somewhat language-lawyer question indeed.  Thank you very much for trying compiling though.

Comment: @user2357112: It's hard to say whether a deleted function "exists" or not.  A deleted copy constructor can even participate in overload resolution.

Comment: Your example of the problem is ignoring the "and is declared without an initializer (8.5)." requirement which precludes a class with a deleted trivial default constructor from getting into such a situation: the declaration would be ill-formed.

Comment: @Casey: You're correct.  My fault of this overlook.  Really sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[CWG issue 667](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#667) addressed this exact issue with a change that was incorporated into the C++ working draft near [N3225](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3225.pdf). N3225 § 12.1 [class.ctor]/5 states:

> A default constructor is trivial if it is neither user-provided nor deleted and if:
>
> - its class has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
> - no non-static data member of its class has a *brace-or-equal-initializer*, and
> - all the direct base classes of its class have trivial default constructors, and
> - for all the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial default constructor.
>
> Otherwise, the default constructor is *non-trivial*.

This was (obviously) changed before C++11 release. [CWG DR 1135](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1135) was created to address [a Finland national body comment on the C++11 candidate draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3296.html#FI1):

> It should be allowed to explicitly default a non-public special member function on its first declaration. It is very likely that users will want to default protected/private constructors and copy constructors without having to write such defaulting outside the class.

The resolution of this issue removed the "nor deleted" text from 12.1 as well as the sections describing trivial destructors, trivial copy/move constructors, and trivial copy/move assignment operators. I think this change cut too broad a swath, and it was likely not intentional to make your `struct A` trivial. Indeed, on face value it's ridiculous that this program is ill-formed:

```
int x = 42;
int y = 13;
A a_x{x};
A a_y{y};
a_x = a_y;
```

but this program is not, since `A` is trivially copyable ([Clang agrees](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6a7a279120b2bd0), [GCC does not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d861db014de948c)):

```
int x = 42;
int y = 13;
A a_x{x};
A a_y{y};
std::memcpy(&a_x, &a_y, sizeof(a_x));
```

The existence of [CWG issue 1496 "Triviality with deleted and missing default constructors"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1496) seems to indicate that the committee is aware of the problem (or at least a closely related problem):

> A default constructor that is defined as deleted is trivial, according to 12.1 [class.ctor] paragraph 5. This means that, according to 9 [class] paragraph 6, such a class can be trivial. If, however, the class has no default constructor because it has a user-declared constructor, the class is not trivial. Since both cases prevent default construction of the class, it is not clear why there is a difference in triviality between the cases.

although there is no resolution as yet.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the information.  It seems like a defect in the standard.