# Automatically generated class member functions in C++11 in the case of classes which do not have any constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, class-members

In C++11, I define a struct of the following general form:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    static void myFunc( void );

    //constructors
    MyStruct( void ) = delete;
};
```

It is not possible to create any object of type `MyStruct` as the default constructor is marked deleted. Even the method `myFunc` can't create an instance of the class. The struct is still of use though, as `MyStruct::myFunc` is `public` and can be called from outside.

My question now is: Since it is not possible to create any object of type `MyStruct`, will the compiler even bother to create code for a copy constructor, <strike>address operator or</strike> destructor?

Just as a remark: In the case of my actual code, I really have to implement functionality in terms of static class member functions, as I have to make use of partial template class specialization to emulate partial template function specialization. So I wonder how I can keep the class as slim as possible.

**Edit**: removed the remark about automatically generated address operators in accordance with the comment and answer of @Praetorian.

Comment: What do you mean by *address operator*? Surely not `operator&` - the compiler *never* automatically generates that for you.

Comment: *"So I wonder how I can keep the class as slim as possible"* The compiler will only provide a definition for the special member functions if those are ODR-used.

Comment: @Praetorian: Thank you for the comment, I indeed thought the compiler would define a standard implementation of the address operator with the meaning of "just giving the memory address". I think that I once read such a statement in Effective C++. I may very well be mistaken!

Comment: @dyp: So for a class that never gets instantiated, the compiler never generates code for a default constructor and destructor?!

Comment: I wonder if it is UB to trick the compiler: `std::aligned_storage<sizeof(MyStruct)>::type buffer; MyStruct obj = reinterpret_cast<MyStruct*>(&buffer);` -- since the object has no members, no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion should take place. But of course this is silly / purely academic.

Comment: @sperber Exactly. (If you explicitly default a special member function outside the class body, the compiler will always provide a definition. But otherwise, only if ODR-used.)

Comment: @dyp That cast is (currently) a valid way to get a `MyStruct*`, a [default constructor deleted on its first declaration is considered trivial since it's not user-provided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812183/a-deleted-default-constructor-could-still-be-trivial). [CWG 1496](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1496) indicates that this may be a flaw in the language, but the committee has not yet decided how to address it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler will *implicitly declare* both a destructor and copy constructor for your class, but since you have no way of creating an instance of the class, your program will never be able to odr-use either the destructor or copy constructor, because of which neither will be *implicitly defined*.

*§12.4 [class.dtor]*

> *4*   If a class has no user-declared destructor, a destructor is implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4). An implicitly declared destructor is an `inline public` member of its class.
>   *5*   A destructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is odr-used (3.2) to destroy an object of its class type (3.7) or when it is explicitly defaulted after its first declaration.

*§12.8 [class.copy]*

> *7*   If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4). The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared destructor.
>   *13*   A copy/move constructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is implicitly defined if it is odr-used (3.2) or when it is explicitly defaulted after its first declaration.

As for the address operator (`operator&`), the compiler never generates that operator overload for you implicitly. The built-in address of operator can be applied to any lvalue type to take its address, but that's a language feature, and unrelated to overloading that operator for a user defined type.

Comment: It's possible to create instances of trivially constructible classes without ever invoking a constructor, since [basic.life]/1 only requires initialization for objects with non-trivial initialization. [class.ctor]/5 says that a default constructor deleted on its first declaration is trivial. [So it's possible to ODR-use the copy/move constructors and destructor of `MyStruct` in a conforming - albeit ridiculously contrived - program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6377027778004635).

Comment: @Casey Wow, you should really post that as an answer ... not that anyone should consider something like that a valid use case :)